# @preauthorize spring boot shows access right error

Tags: java, spring-boot

my **securityConfig.java** look like this and in my project there are so many Access rights and i write only the below securityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)  
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    protected SecurityConfig(final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        super();
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/pub/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationTokenFilter(this.tokenAuthenticationService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().httpBasic().and()
                .csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                }).authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                });
    }
}
```

It shows **Access denied error** and my intention is use to display user details who have GET_USER access right.
And the **controller** file look this and i tried both ROLE_GET_USR and GET_USR.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('GET_USR')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/min", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserMinimalData() {
        final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("User name " + auth.getName()); // prints - User name pratap
        System.out.println("User Authorities " + auth.getAuthorities()); // prints - User Authorities [ADMIN]
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.facade.getUserMinimalData(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: How do you set the roles for the user?

Comment: @1615903 i dont set the roles yet. where i can set the roles?please give some instruction

Comment: @1615903  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('**GET_USR**')")` and @PreAuthorize("hasRole('**ROLE_GET_USR**')") this both options i tried . i think i have to write GET_USR **access write** code in my java configuration file. if you  do like this please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller please use hasAuthority instead of hasRole

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('GET_USR')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/min", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserMinimalData() {
        final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("User name " + auth.getName()); // prints - User name pratap
        System.out.println("User Authorities " + auth.getAuthorities()); // prints - User Authorities [ADMIN]
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.facade.getUserMinimalData(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```